# Solve issue: Checking is logged

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm testing whatsapp bot with **node js** and **venom-bot** and the code stays processing `Cheking is logged...` and never stops.

[CMD - Print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBg8X.png)

In the first attemp, the code runs okay, showing me Whatsapp's QRCode, however,once I scanned it, shut down the program and start again, the code falls in line `Checking is logged`.

It's my code in **index.js** file:

```
// Supports ES6
// import { create, Whatsapp } from 'venom-bot';
const venom = require('venom-bot');

venom
  .create('test-user')
  .then((client) => start(client))
  .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });

function start(client) {
  client.onMessage((message) => {
    if (message.body === 'Hi' && message.isGroupMsg === false) {
      client
        .sendText(message.from, 'Welcome Venom ')
        .then((result) => {
          console.log('Result: ', result); //return object success
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Error when sending: ', error); //return object error
        });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Issue was solved in an issue in Venom Git Hub' Repo: https://github.com/orkestral/venom/issues/782**